# Link outside div tag encompasses empty space

Tags: html

I have a link outside a div like in the following example:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
    <div id="Something" style="width:200px; height:100px; display:block; background-color:red; padding:0; margin:0;">
    </div>
</a>
```

Now, the link does work on any part of the div, but it is also present outside the div, mainly to the right side of it where there isn't anything. How can I fix this to make the link only work inside the div tag?

Here's the code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BWPHS/

Comment: That's not a valid way of doing it. Make the `A` tag `display: block` *inside* the DIV.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Depending on the doctype, I think [wrapping an `<a>` around block-level elements actually is valid](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/).

Comment: @sdleihssirhc - Ok, HTML5 does allow (didn't know that). All kinds of goodies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, `DIV` elements are `display: block` by default, so you don't need that in the `DIV`. What you do need to do is make the `A` the same height, and resolve the padding and margin to taste.

```
<div id="Something" style="width:200px; height:100px; background-color:red; padding:0; margin:0;">
    <a href="http://google.com" style="height: 100px; display:block; padding: 0; margin: 0;"></a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BWPHS/3/

Note, as sdleihssirc notes, HTML5 does allow it (if you use the DOCTYPE). Note, to resolve the specific issue for HTML5, you would need to apply the height and width to the `A` tag:

```
<a href="http://google.com" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; display:block; padding: 0; margin: 0; background: blue;">
    <div id="Something" style="height: 100px; background-color: red; padding:0; margin:0;"></div>
</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BWPHS/2/

And, as thirtydot points out, you can `display: inline-block` or `float: left` the `#something` element and apply `display: block` to the `A` and it should work perfectly for you:

```
#something,
#something a {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#something {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
#something a:link {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

<div id="something">
    <a href="http://google.com"></a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BWPHS/6/

And you probably want to try to avoid using inline `style` attributes.

Comment: It would be better to drop the `width` and `height` from the `div` to avoid duplication, and use `float: left` or `display: inline-block` instead.

Comment: @thirtydot - Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/BWPHS/5/ (The small gap at the bottom is a bit of a problem.)

Comment: Yeah, that's it. You can get rid of the gap at the bottom by adding `vertical-align: top` to the `a` (or simply using `display: block` on the `a` instead of `display: inline-block`).

Comment: @thirtydot - This is probably more like what you were thinking (and no gap): http://jsfiddle.net/BWPHS/6/

Comment: Looking good. I'd give you an upvote if I hadn't already given you an upvote.